# Mediawiki wgUseFileCache with api calls

Tags: media, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have a media wiki instance which gets lots of get api calls. I would like to use the in built file cache (wgUseFileCache) but it looks like it only works for web page requests. Is it possible to use a file cache on the api?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to use file cache for Api requests. To achieve what you want, you can use other caching layers, too, e.g. [Varnish](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Varnish_caching) or (probably you use it already as a webserver) nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Some API modules cache data internally, so make sure [$wgMainCacheType](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMainCacheType) is set to something reasonable, but as Florian says, MediaWiki itself does not cache API output. It does set proper cache headers however, so you can use mod_cache or whatever on top of it.